# Undistorting concentric circles in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image consisting of concentric circles. I'm trying to undistort the image so that the circles are equal spacing apart around the edges, as if the camera is parallel to the plane. (Some circles will appear closer to the next which is fine, I just want equal spacing all around the edges between the two adjacent circles)

I've tried to estimate a rigid transform by specifying points of the outer circle, but it distorts the inner circles too much, and I've tried a findhomography by specifying points of all the circles, and comparing with points of circles of where they should be.

From what I see the outer circles are 'squished' vertically, so need to be smushed up horizontally, but the inner circles are more circular. What can I do to undistort this image?

[image]

Comment: do the circles really lie on a plane? shouldnt they all be distorted in the same way?!? If they're all on a plane, homography would really be the thing you want to use (if your data is correct enough).

Comment: is the image upside down ? or the one you posted on irc yesterday ;) ? what is your next step after finding a transformation matrix ? is the  image the real thing even, or a mockup for something else ?

Comment: is it enough to transform the rings, or do you need the space between them interpolated as well ?

Comment: @Micka you're right. They're not on a planar surface, but after reading as much as I could about homography, I thought it could be estimated to be? If not, what could I use, I don't have measurements of the depth. Nor do I have access to the camera for calibration photos.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry for the other post. apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/ipwithopencv/source/browse/trunk/ThinPlateSpline/ThinPlateSpline/?r=4

Using this implementation of Thin Plate Spline, I was able to input a set of points representing all the distorted circles, and another set of points which represent where they should be, to get the desired output. It isn't absolutely perfect, but it's more than good enough!